# GCP cloudsql user roles association by terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-sql

I'm asking this question as I did not find the answer to this specific point anywhere.

I'm using terraform to create a cloudsql, it's users and databases. This is relatively simple but it gets complicated when you are trying to limit the users inside the cloudsql (postgres/mysql...).

To not have multiple super-user, I'm using the iam service account user type when creating the user, meaning the user won't have any rights to do anything but connect to the cloudsql but I would like to be able, in terraform, to associate the account I create with a database but that doesn't seems possible currently with the available options of database or users resources.

Does anyone has an idea on how to do that?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't. The thing that you want to achieve is performed by a query inside the DB engine. And with Terraform, you can't connect inside the instance, only interact with the API that manage the instance.

Comment: I've never tried this, but using a Postgres provider (or similar for other engines) might make this possible: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cyrilgdn/postgresql/latest/docs.

Comment: The postgres engine is not really a good idea as you can't really test it outside a a CI that run inside the project. And I would like to prevent that. It's a shame that they don't give an owner option on the database on creation that would be really perfect.

Comment: It is not clear what operations you are performing and what is the outcome you expect. If you are trying to associate the account you have created with a database you have created you may check [adding IAM users](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/add-manage-iam-users) and [IAM policy for service accounts](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_service_account_iam). Using a combination of terraform for Cloud SQL and IAM policies you should likely be able to grant accounts access to database as you expect.

Comment: There is no way, that I know of, of giving database rights (postgres, mysql...) through iam policy, roles are not aware in any way of the databases existing inside a cloudsql...

Comment: Can you check these two page https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/sql_user and https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_project_iam